# What author citation and abbreviation does (would) a monarch or a crown prince get after publishing a new taxon name?

Tags: taxonomy

Even though taxonomic rules appear to be silent about this (I've checked ICN Art. 46 and ICZN Art. 51), author citations, as well as abbreviations, are usually based on a surname. However, monarchs and crown princes don't have surnames *per se*, at least in the Western culture. Even though they have dynasty names, they may only get referred to by their personal name and dynasty name used as (instead of) a surname after the monarchy was overthrown, and for our purpose let's assume otherwise.

Has there ever been a case when such a person, while practicing biology (either as a hobby or professionally) published a name for a new taxon and there was a need to make up an author citation/abbreviation? If yes, how was it (they) made? If no, what would be an author citation/abbreviation for someone like, e. g., British Prince William?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about taxonomic nomenclature, but my gut feeling on this matter seems to be correct — the Christian or given name is used. The [“List of organisms named after famous people” on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_organisms_named_after_famous_people) includes:

> *Callicebus bernhardi* — Prince Bernhard of Lippe-Biesterfeld
>
> *Megaselia mithridatesi* — Mithridates VI of Pontus
>
> *Mitra kamehameha* — King Kamehameha I
>
> *Ornithoptera alexandrae* — Alexandra of Denmark
>
> *Paroxyna cleopatra* — Cleopatra VII Philopator
>
> *Pinus montezumae* — Moctezuma II
>
> *Victoria* Lindl. — Queen Victoria

However this is not always unqualified — perhaps because he is not the monarch?:

> *Hyloscirtus princecharlesi* — Charles, Prince of Wales

and there are exceptions:

> *Lepidoteuthis grimaldii* — Albert I, Prince of Monaco (born Albert Grimaldi)